# Sharepoint Open Document Class add-on for 64bit IE

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, browser-addons, ieaddon

I am having problems with Sharepoint Open Document Class ad-on when using 64bit IE, documents simply won't open on some computers. On those computers, I see the add-on on the 64bit IE but it says that is only 32-bit under Architecture field.

On the other hand, I have another computer using perfectly the 64-bit IE, and sees the add-on like this:

[image]

I read tons of posts on this subject, like [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-seamlessly-between-Office-Online-and-Office-desktop-applications-2d43ec7b-d173-4c06-91d7-7c5425990093?CorrelationId=8cf3d430-3d35-4939-b68c-28c4d3e634e1&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and [this](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/ie-64-bit-does-not-allow-document-library-to-be-opened-in) and they all say it´s not possible but despite that, I have one case where it actually works.

Is it possible that the add-on CAN work with 64-bit IE, but ONLY if the local isntallation of the Office is 64-bit edition as well or this things are not related?

Thank you so much!

Comment: On the computer that has the mysterious 32-bit and 64-bit version, from the manage add-ons window, right-click on SharePoint OpenDocuments Class and choose more information to see where that DLL is coming from (that is, its folder). Normally it is added to a computer by Microsoft Office, and will be located in a corresponding Microsoft Office folder under Program Files. If you can determine how that DLL was added, you might be able to duplicate the process on another computer (such as by installing the same Office applications).

Comment: Thank you!! I´ll try that. So it is indeed possible that it depends on the office version that is installed on the PC.. right??

Comment: That's my theory, anyway! If you do find out what application install provided that DLL, please post it as an answer to your question. I'd be very curious to know where that working DLL came from!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Thriggle suggestion, I checked which program was providing the dll for the add-on, and it was Office 2016 indeed.

So I am guessing that the problem is the bit-version of the Office installation.

I'll try re-installing the Office on my client's computer to see if the add-on starts working with a 64-bit Internet Explorer.

Thank you very much!